# E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(571)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE for android tv

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I am trying playing html page in android Xiomi tv box, it runs but it plays slowly and gives below error in console, When try other devices like Samsung phone it plays normally, how can I solve this problem for xiomi tv box?

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(571)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=953ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=530522424163, Vsync=531039090809, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=531049763957, AnimationStart=531050344623, PerformTraversalsStart=531056490332, DrawStart=531059717041, SyncQueued=531065513916, SyncStart=531100647087, IssueDrawCommandsStart=531100778878, SwapBuffers=531510354628, FrameCompleted=531511511253, DequeueBufferDuration=314000, QueueBufferDuration=783000,I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

MainActivity

```
webViewBackground = findViewById(R.id.wbVw_bacground);
webViewBackground.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewBackground.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webViewBackground.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/bg.html");
```

Xml

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wbVw_bacground"
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late to answer this question, I encountered the same issue while implementing a WebView. The error is thrown because [DOM Api Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) is usually disabled by default from WebView settings. Set `setDomStorageEnabled()` to `true` and load your web URL again.

```
binding.webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```